# Parallels Coherence Mode: Two Instances of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, osx-elcapitan, parallels

Is it possible to open two instances of Visual Studio in Parallels while in Coherence mode?  If I try to open a second solution, Visual Studio closes the current solution and opens the new solution in the same VS instance.

Environment Information:
Macbook Pro w/Retina
El Capitan (OS 10.11)
Parallels 11
Windows 10.1
Visual Studio 2015

Comment: How are you attempting to open the second solution?  If you're in the first instance, and then open a separate/second solution, Visual Studio will always close the first solution first. However, if you open a second instance of Visual Studio, THEN open the second solution in that second instance, everything should be fine.  Clear as mudd?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  There's a little more nuance here than I realized.  To answer your question, I'm using File Explorer and opening the file directly.  I think I see the problem I was having though.  Two instances are in fact opening, but if you are using Apple-Tab to cycle through the open apps, only a single instance of Visual Studio will show up in the app list.  If any Windows app is in focus and you use alt-Tab, the other instance of Visual Studio will show up in the app list.